# How to get a state URL without params?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an state in angular-ui router:

```
.state('example', {
    url: '/example?foo&bar',
    templateUrl: '/partials/example.html',
    controller: 'ExampleController'
})
```

In *ExampleController*, I do:

```
console.log($state.href('example', {}, {inherit: false}));
```

Then I navigate my app to `/example?foo=1&bar=2`.
I expect that my controller will log just ***/example* (for creating canonical url later)**
But it always log the exactly the current state `/example?foo=1&bar=2`.

What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ui-router` has 2 inforamtion, we can use for logging.

- The `$state` **name** *('example' in our case)*
- and **url** string, representing the *pattern* of the 1) state name + 2) param names *('/example?foo&bar' in our case)*.

That's it - there isn't any separated information: *state url without params...*

Here is [an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/PiEFy6IjVi8X6ncgHL9j?p=preview) showing what the state does contain. So let's even extend the above state with id parameter:

```
.state('example2', {
  url: '/example2/:id?foo&bar',
  templateUrl: '/partials/example.html',
  controller: 'ExampleController',
})
```

and if we observe such a current state **`<a ui-sref="example2({id: 222, foo:2,bar:4})">`** we can see:

```
{
  "params": {
    "id": "222",
    "foo": "2",
    "bar": "4"
  },
  "current": {
    "url": "/example2/:id?foo&bar",
    "templateUrl": "/partials/example.html",
    "controller": "ExampleController",
    "name": "example2"
  },
  "transition": null
}
```

So, I would suggest: if you need loggin just a states.. use the `$state.current.name`

Comment: I have update my question, the issue is I need a "canonical url".

Comment: I'm trying to say, that this is different from the ui-router url handling. There could be even parts like `/state1/:param/state2` ... and then parts without parameter will not make sense. Other words, I would suggest to log the state names, which do not depend on url *(which could be not set for abstract states)* and also does not get dirty by params... just a suggestion ;)

Comment: ahh, I understand, tks you!

Comment: Great if that helped anyhow ;) enjoy `ui-router` awesome tool ;)